# Trump's lawyer, Sidney Powell, is making some pretty extraordinary claims of electoral fraud. What is her reputation in the legal community?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, election-fraud

Trump's lawyer, Sidney Powell, is making some pretty wild claims about [alleging massive electoral fraud](https://youtu.be/fT-udMDpCtU?t=2301) in the 2020 election. What she's alleging would be (if true) the biggest scandal since the [1876 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_Commission_(United_States)#Election_of_1876), which saw thousands of ballots thrown out in the states of Florida, Louisiana and South Carolina and came close to sparking a second civil war. There are some [sworn](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/18632787/6/19/wood-v-raffensperger/) [affidavits](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.gand.283580/gov.uscourts.gand.283580.7.1_2.pdf) alleging impropriety, but she's claiming that most of the evidence will be "presented at trial" so isn't available yet.

Given the current lack of evidence, the only way for me to evaluate these claims is to determine her **credibility**. Strictly as a lawyer in pre-Trump cases, **what is her record for making allegations that were then subsequently proven or failed to be proven in a court of law?** A good answer will include such things as a Win/Loss record, professional sanctions, accolades, high profile cases and the like.

Comment: This might be a better fit on Law.SE, though I recommend making sure it is in line with their guidelines before posting there.

Comment: A lawyers reputation doesn't have anything to do with politics.

Comment: It does when she's alleging massive electoral fraud without evidence (yet). We need to know if she's a credible person or not.

Comment: Her reputation doesn’t directly tie to her credibility and you could stretch that logic to try and make anything related to election fraud claims related to politics when that wouldn’t be the case. As an example she should have a reputation as a great (or crappy) lawyer but that wouldn’t mean she is seen as credible as that just shows how she is seen for her work.

Comment: See https://www.charlotteobserver.com/news/politics-government/election/article247313859.html

Comment: Trump’s former lawyer, now.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/nov/23/trump-campaign-cuts-ties-with-attorney-sidney-powell-after-bizarre-election-claims - Link to a story for more on the "former lawyer" situation.

Answer (score 7):

The highlights of Powell's legal career can be found on [her Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Powell). She served as an assistant district attorney in Texas before starting up her own law firm. She has a penchant for taking on 'celebrity' cases — the Enron scandal in the 2000s, and Michal Flynn's case in 2019 — and has made numerous appearances on (primarily conservative) media opinion shows. Her success record on these prominent cases is not stellar, but that is not necessarily a reflection on her capabilities as a lawyer. Some lawyers take on mostly hopeless cases on because even hopeless cases have a right to representation, and positioning oneself as a 'fighter' builds reputation even if the outcome is a loss.

Like all lawyers, Powell has a thin line to walk: she must simultaneously defend her client's interests as an advocate and meet basic legal requirements. Failing either side could cost her her reputation or even her license. Trump is fixated on the 'massive voter fraud' narrative, so Powell would be obliged to advance it whether or not she believes it is true, so long as she can meet some minimal due diligence with respect to the court. I suspect that if this ever went to trial she would produce some small number of sworn affidavits — a token needed to satisfy her responsibilities to the court — but that all of them would either be recanted or dismissed by the court.

Remember, Powell — like everyone else in the country with a lick of sense — realizes that the point of these lawsuits is not to present a credible case that can be won in court. The point is to delay certification of the election results so that state legislatures can co-opt the process and appoint electors by fiat. Trump doesn't want the *courts* to decide the election in these states any more than he wants the *people* to decide the election, because in either case he would lose. He wants the decision shifted over to partisan legislatures who might be willing to do his bidding.

Comment: I think you're giving her a bit too much credit here, given that she is a qanon conspiracy theorist who thinks that T̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶o̶l̶s̶h̶e̶v̶i̶k̶ J̶e̶w̶s̶ George Soros and the communists rigged the election.

Comment: Does she have a record of making outlandish claims and then failing to supply evidence?

Comment: @tim: I tend to give lawyers the benefit of the doubt, because lawyers are professionally jaded. You can rarely tell when they themselves actually believe something, or when they are merely spewing client-centered bullshit for the court.

Comment: You were good until that last paragraph.

Comment: You claim to know what Powell is thinking/believes. You don't unless you're a mind reader or unless she has expressed his publicly. If the latter is true, then you should probably cite where she has said this. If not, then you should probably consider rewording or removing that last paragraph.